# Xamarin forms button stilling

Tags: forms, xamarin, navigation

I have Xamarin form application. In App.xaml.cs I have event handler for button. If I set different background color on click it works. If I have also navigation like Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new Page1()) color doesn't change. How navigation break background color change?

```
 private void Navigate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button? button = sender as Button;
            if (button != null)
            {
                Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(new Page1());
                button.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#332196F3");
                
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code that actually demonstrates the issue.  You have only posted a single line of code - it's impossible to tell exactly what you are doing or which element's background color you are talking about,.

Comment: you are pushing a new page onto the stack, so that the old page containing the button is no longer visible.

Comment: My button is defined in App.xaml. It is something like main page that keep button and Page1 is set in ContentPresenter in App.xaml. Button is still visible but background color is default one.

Comment: if your button is defined across the application, maybe you should set the backgroundcolor via a `DynamicResource`. And then, if you want to change it, use `Resources ["buttonBackcolor"] = Color.FromHex("332196F3");`

Comment: The problem is that color is applied only if I commented row with navigation. If navigation is active color is the default one.

Comment: Could you provide the code for us to reproduce?